# SQL Server injection

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

New to web development and taking over someones code. They have a function to prevent sql injection, for SQL Server database

```
function safe(val, maxsize)
   dim i,
   terms = array(
      "cast",
      "select",
      "varchar",
      "declare",
      "drop",
      ";",
      "--",
      "insert",
      "delete",
      "xp_"
   )
   val = left(val,maxsize)
   val = trim(val)
   for i = 0 to ubound(terms)
      val = replace(val, terms(i), "e_" & val & "_e", vbTextCompare)
   next
   val = replace(val, "'", "''")
   makesafe = val
end function
```

Hesitant to touch this, but is this missing anything? Seems occasionally they get hacked

Comment: If they get hacked then they should deal with injection correctly - use parameterized statements, with correct data types, validate the input and don't blindly build SQL statements based on strings submitted by users (or even the app). This "safe" function feels like a false security blanket to me.

Comment: Using **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL statements yourself is the **ONLY** viable way to go. Forget "sanitizing" your inputs - you'll always forget something - just use parametrized queries and be done with it....

Comment: This definitely is a false and dangerous security blanket. For one example, it is missing the `update` keyword in the terms array. `update` can be just as damaging if misused as any of the other terms. `go` isn't listed either. You really need to study up on SQL Injection and then formulate an implementation/update strategy. This function simply won't do.

Comment: @Paul I think the more important point is that it is fruitless to try and create the "perfect" function. Ever try to create a perfect RegEx for validating an e-mail address? Something will *always* get left out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following article should help :

http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/sql-injection-vs-lethal-injection-protection-against-sql-injection

It is not good idea to go down this path with `string.Replace`

Comment: +1 absolutely - the only useful solution is **parametrized queries** as this article shows nicely

Comment: @marc_s totally agreed. Also, EntityFramework or Linq to SQL would help as well.

Comment: This looks like VBScript in classic ASP, so it might be a little more involved to move to EF or Linq2SQL.

Comment: @Aaron yeah, right. But who develop apps on VBScript anymore? If it is a legacy app, I would look ant the ways of migrating it. ASP.NET vNext is on the way.

Comment: I still do, because I don't need all of the added functionality and I can develop an ASP app in half the time. That's not the answer for everyone, but neither are EF, Linq, etc. If classic ASP is what the user is currently running, migrating to a different technology might not be justified just to thwart SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

I would completely scrap that function and start using a parameterized statement like Aaron mentioned in his comment.  If you haven't done so before, there are various [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) on how to do so.  In the article I linked you to, look at step 2.

Answer (score 2):

I would not rely on such a function to prevent sql injection attacks. Parameterized queries are a must. There are almost surely some injection texts you will miss using the approach of the method you listed.